# Why tooltip is not getting initialized

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

Here is my code :

```
$(oContainer).find('a').tooltip ({
  selector  : "[data-toggle=tooltip]",
  title     : 'sTooltip',
  placement : 'auto',
  container : 'body',
  trigger   : 'hover'
});
```

Comment: Is there any error in browser console?

Comment: nope, no error in console, showing tooltip but not as expected means

simply comment code

$(document).ready(function(){debugger;
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();   
});
from following and same:

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_tooltip&stacked=h

Answer (score 0):

Tooltips rely on the 3rd party library `Tether` for positioning. You must include `tether.min.js` before `bootstrap.js` in order for tooltips to work!

Reference - https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/tooltips/#overview

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

element on which i was applying tool tip was getting cloned by library.

so as element is cloned it's events were getting removed.

that's why tool tip was not showing.

I just let library clone element then, I added tooltip and it worked